# How can deloyed tokens(JWT Tokens) in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, jwt

Im deployed on heroku and something like this....

[image]

I also insert TOKEN_SECRET on the config vars(HEROKU app)

[image]

Here is my syntax and BTW I set already the syntax on .env file.....

```
.env

MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://borgons:mandawe@cluster0.vp4uw.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
TOKEN_SECRET = secret
```

```
middleware/auth.js -- where set my declare my process.env.TOKEN_SECRET

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require("dotenv").config();

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
   
   const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
   const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

   if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

   jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
      req.user = user;
      next();
   });
}

function generateAccessToken(username) {
   return jwt.sign({ data: username }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '1h',
   });
}

module.exports = {
   authenticateToken,
   generateAccessToken
}
```

On running it on development and its ok but the production (deploy on heroku) its not ok.... and always PORT 401 unauthorized...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the request header contains the keyword(example: Bearer) along with the token:

[image]